# Загрузить HTML страницу с внешними ссылками на картинки не сохраняя ее на жесткий диск

Tags: html, visual-c++

Доброго времени суток.

Необходимо загрузить и отобразить HTML страницу с внешними ссылками на картинки без сохранения HTML и ресурсов на жесткий диск. Причем HTML страница будет браться из базы данных (не с веб сервера) вместе с ресурсами.

При помощи чего такое можно провернуть?

Пытаемся заполнить IHTMLDocument, но как подгрузить ресурсы картинок, пока не понятно. Может это можно как-то сделать через SAFEARRAY, но как пока не придумали :-)

Comment: я бы сделал по простому - поднял на локалхосте простой http сервер. Он будет в базу бегать и отдавать страницы/картинки/скрипты.

А IHTMLDocument просто делает `navigate2("http://localhost:8888");`

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо, рассматривали данный вариант, но не хотелось бы разворачивать вебсервер. Мы скорее всего лучше формат пересмотрим, чем создавать вебсервер будем.

Comment: Есть ещё один вариант. Можно создать свой "протокол". То есть, вместо "http://" у Вас будет "page://". В этом случае оно будет работать и в отдельно стоящем IE.

в самой винде это используется по полной. тот же протокол "file://".

Comment: @kovadim, а как-нибудь заполнить imagelist можно из стрима? Документ там хранит загруженные картинки. Хотелось бы список заполнить картинками, сунуть ему html и получить готовый документ для отображения. 
На счёт протокола, это конечно идея, но как раз нужно ограничить доступ к информации, и предоставлять его исключительно из определённого приложения.

Comment: > а как-нибудь заполнить imagelist можно из стрима?

даже не знаю.

Но если Вы боитесь, что у Вас своруют информацию - не показывайте ее никому. Абсолютно. 

Но, возможно, решением Вашей проблемы будет mht (он же вебархив) или самый обычный pdf.

Comment: @kovadim, идём по пути наименьшего сопротивления. Сегодня провели исследование, mht формат удовлетворяет основным требованиям, однако я чувствую подвохи на завязку с iexplore со всеми вытекающими, в том числе ie6.0.

Исследование будет продолжаться с изучением формата mht, мне казался он вымирающим, но обнаружил, что его почти все браузеры читают, хотя об этом и умалчивают.

Ps:Оберните свой комментарий в ответ, чтобы я мог принять его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

подсумируем все. Есть следующие варианты:

- создание своего локального вебсервера.
- создание [пользовательского протокола](IInternetProtocol), например "page://". [пример](http://k210.org/delphi/internet/79/).
- использование pdf
- использование mht.